# LocalReportExtension, how to print in Monochrome rather than color?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms

Im trying to print a RDLC report in C# however when the user presses print, visual studio prints the page in color which is not cost efficient.

I use a localreportExtension class to print the page however
`pageSettings.Color = false;` doesnt work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace PrintToPrinter
{
    public static class LocalReportExtensionscs
    {
        public static void PrintToPrinter(this LocalReport report)
        {
            var pageSettings = new PageSettings();
            pageSettings.Color = false;
            pageSettings.PaperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize;
            pageSettings.Landscape = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().IsLandscape;
            pageSettings.Margins = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins;
            pageSettings.Landscape = true;

            Print(report, pageSettings);
        }

        public static void Print(this LocalReport report, PageSettings pageSettings)
        {
            pageSettings.Color = false;
            string deviceInfo =
                $@"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            var streams = new List<Stream>();
            var currentPageIndex = 0;
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo,
                (name, fileNameExtension, encoding, mimeType, willSeek) =>
                {
                    var stream = new MemoryStream();
                    streams.Add(stream);
                    return stream;
                }, out warnings);
            foreach(Stream stream in streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
            if(streams.Equals(null)||streams.Count==0)
                throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
            var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
            if(!printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
                throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
            else
            {
                printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(streams[currentPageIndex]);
                    Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                        e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                        e.PageBounds.Width,
                        e.PageBounds.Height);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);
                    currentPageIndex++;
                    e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count);
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect);
                };
                printDocument.EndPrint += (Sender, e) =>
                {
                    if(streams != null)
                    {
                        foreach(Stream stream in streams)
                            stream.Close();
                        streams = null;
                    }
                };
                printDocument.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am i missing to print the page in black and white?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unrelated, but would it be possible to add/inject some CSS to the page to force grayscale printing?

```
    @media print {
      body {
         filter: Gray();
         -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
         filter: grayscale(100%); 
       }
    }
```